# Using a Submix track for Multicam in Premiere

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

In Premiere CC 2014, I am using a Multicam Sequence that uses the topmost audio track when changing cameras.

I have a few audio tracks that I want mix, so I mapped them all to a submix track

Is it possible for a Multicam sequence to use the Submix track instead of the topmost track?